# Don't see interactive markers in MoveIt demo.launch

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have done the moveit configuration procedure for my robot, however when I launch the demo.launch I don't see the interactive markers in RViz. I have defined four planning groups and kinematic solvers for these groups (KDL) in the kinematics.yaml file. I do get a warning when launching the demo, that no parent groups have been defined for my end effectors. What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110096/don%27t-see-interactive-markers-in-moveit-demo.launch/) by [sofiad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8786/sofiad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just solved my problem: I didn't have the parent link for the end-effector properly configured in my srdf file.

Thanks anyway!

---

Originally posted by [sofiad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8786/sofiad/) with karma: 58 on 2013-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2014-02-25**:
Could you elaborate about what change made your configuration proper? I have the same problem and haven't found the trick yet.